# PyQt window crashes after launch

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to launch the following code. The Application window opens but as soon as I click on the button, the window crashes.

```
import sys
from qtpy import QtWidgets
from src.ui.mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from src.Run_OMD_Process import run_omd

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("OMD Tool")
        print("MainWindow")
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onPushOmdButton)
        # self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.exitUi)

    def onPushOmdButton(self):
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(run_omd())


window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is crashing because you left the parentheses on your `run_omd` call when you connected it to your button in `onPushOmdButton`.

Try:

```
self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(run_omd)
```

This method is also only reconnecting the button to a different function.  So basically, you will have to click the button twice to get the result I believe you are after.  I'm not sure if this is what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with MalloyDekacroix on this one:

```
import sys
from pyqt import QtWidgets
from src.ui.mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from src.Run_OMD_Process import run_omd

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("OMD Tool")
        print("Main`enter code here`Window")
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onPushOmdButton)
        # self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.exitUi)

    def onPushOmdButton(self):
        // i.e. this could so something else. 
        // for instance, open a new window.
        // perform a calculation.
        // As your code I also feel requires the user to click again. 

window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```